# How far can a unit upgrade itself through finding ruins?

Tags: civilization-5

Units can be upgraded through finding advanced weaponry in ruins. How far ahead of the current technology level can they be upgraded? If I found enough ruins, could I theoretically have a mechanized infantry in the first age?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A unit can only be upgraded once. Originally this was possible, but it was patched.